# IE9 diminui largura de barra lateral com scroll auto

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Estou enfrentando um problema de layout com o IE9.

Em uma certa página que estou desenvolvendo, há uma barra de menus lateral com propriedade CSS `overflow-y: auto` para que uma barra de rolagem apareça caso o conteúdo no menu não caiba na parte definida para ela. O comportamento ocorre de forma correta em todos os navegadores. A barra de rolagem aparece por cima da barra de menu no canto direito. Ocorre que, no navegador IE9, quando a barra de rolagem surge, a largura da barra de menus diminui consideravelmente, causando uma quebra de linha em alguns elementos do menu.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Já tentou `overflow-y: scroll;`?

Comment: Felipe, com o *overflow-y: scroll* a barra de rolagem permanece sempre visível. Resolve o problema da largura, mas causa problemas de design. Preferiria uma solução que não envolvesse isso.

Comment: Sem olhar a página ou o código fica difícil emular testes.

Comment: Matheus, se você fizer um fiddle com o seu caso, poderemos ajudar melhor.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.